# Replacing resource import from old library by import from new library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, import

I had run into a problem in my javascript project. I was using a resource from a library in my project, and I need to replace all instances of it by a resource of the same name, but from another library. The problem is that I'm importing this resource in more than a hundred files alongisde other resources.

What I need is to replace all instances of something that looks like this:

```
import {someResource, changedResource, anotherResource} from 'old-library'
```

By this:

```
import {someResource, anotherResource} from 'old-library'
import {changedResource} from 'new-library'
```

I need to keep the old imports that includes this resource that I want to get from the new library as well as importing the changed resource from the new library. Is that a way I can do that in Visual Code or I'll need to use some script in order to do that?

Comment: To make it more clear, the changedResource can be imported alongside any number of resources. So it only follows this pattern:

import {...anyResources, changedResource, ...anyOtherResources} from 'old-library'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click project root folder ---> find in folder ---> expand the filter

for every "import {someResource, anotherResource} from 'old-library'" you should replace with "import {someResource, anotherResource} from 'old-library'
import {changedResource} from 'new-library'"

example

[image]

becomes

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful. But the 'changedResource' can be imported alongside many different resources. It's usually something like 'import {...., changedResource, ....} from 'old-library'. So  I was looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: @LucasNovaes Ah, I understand now. That sort of wizardry is above my paygrade haha. I'd bet you will need a script.

Comment: Update: I solved my problem by creating a Node.js script that goes through all the files and makes the necessary modifications. It was a bit of a hassle but it as worth it.